# How to update database directly from a TableView or TableWidget?

Tags: c++, sql, oracle, qt-creator

How to update the database directly from a TableView or TableWidget with Qt?
I tried this but it doesn't work:

```
QSqlTableModel* model = new QSqlTableModel;
model->setTable( "fidels" );
model->setEditStrategy(QSqlTableModel::OnManualSubmit);
model->select();
ui->tableView->setModel(model);
```

*From the comments:*

```
QSqlTableModel* carte_fidelite::afficher() {
    QSqlTableModel *model=new QSqlTableModel;
    model->setEditStrategy(QSqlTableModel::OnRowChange);
    model->setTable("fidels");
    model->select();
    return model;
}
cf carte_fidelite;
cf.afficher->submitall();
```

Comment: In what way does it not work? Have you looked at the Qt SQL examples?

Comment: The code looks like it should work. Are you executing this in a slot that is called multiple times? Do you call submitAll()? The documentation states that ***All changes will be cached in the model until either submitAll() or revertAll() is called.***

Comment: @PaulFloyd it doesn t change in my database !!

Comment: @drescherjm i called it in each slot when i want just to display my db.
can you explain it again clearly about submitAll and revevertAll ?

Comment: Since you are using the edit strategy `QSqlTableModel::OnManualSubmit` you must call submitAll at some point after making changes or your database will not change. I assume you would have some **Save Changes** button on your GUI connected to a slot that calls submitAll() on your model.

Comment: yes i did it but no changes in db.

Comment: Show how you call submitAll() in your slot. Perhaps you are using the wrong model pointer since you declared your model as a local variable in your example code. This is okay to do that but then you need to ask the QTableView for the model pointer.

Comment: Also since submitAll() is a slot in QSqlTableModel you could just connect it to a signal from your widget and have it execute when a button is pressed.

Comment: QSqlTableModel*carte_fidelite::afficher()
{
    QSqlTableModel *model=new QSqlTableModel;
    model->setEditStrategy(QSqlTableModel::OnRowChange);

    model->setTable("fidels");
    model->select();


    return model;
}
cf carte_fidelite;
cf.afficher->submitall();

Comment: `cf.afficher->submitall()` what is `cf.afficher` here? Your model is a local variable. I don't see how it has anything to do with `cf.afficher`. Also you don't need that for OnRowChange

Comment: carte_fidelite is a class and afficher() is a function

Comment: do you have another solution ?

Comment: It's difficult to give you a solution because you are posting part of your code (instead of a minimal example showing your problem) and the code you posted does not make sense. I mean `cf.afficher->submitall()` makes no sense at all if `afficher` is a function.

Comment: function return model 
What do you advice me to do ?

Comment: So you meant to write `cf.afficher()->submitall()`

Comment: ***What do you advice me to do ?*** Organize your code and produce a minimal example showing your problem. Then edit your question adding the minimal code.

Comment: i did it but no changes

Comment: No I don't see a minimal example in your question. You posted part of an example. Then put a different part of an example in a comment. Neither of these are complete enough for anyone to test. So it is difficult to understand what mistake you are doing. All I can say is the bug is not in the code presented in the question.